How do I email all members in a Workspace group as a combined group and not just the group's email address?
I have just started using Google Workspace for non-profits as admin and am writing up introductory notes for the charity's trustees partly to persuade them that it's a good idea to use this system, rather than a mixture of email, WhatsApp and text messages.
I am trying to find out how to email a workspace group from Gmail. I have set up two groups: one called 'Trustees' and one called 'General'. I'm not in the Trustees group but I have four test users in the General group and have also added the 'All users' contact which should allow me to contact everyone.
How can I do this for all members of a specific group only - in this case, Trustees?
What do I need to do?

What do you mean by "I have set up two groups"? How did you do that?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

This site isn't intended to assist with administering Google Workspace or to replace other resources. If you have a problem that isn't covered in the docs we can help. Resources: 1. Get started managing groups for an organization 2. Create a group in your organization for email & distribution lists 3. Give a group an additional "alias" address

@Rubén-VolunteerModerator- in the Admin panel, either scroll down till you see a panel named 'Groups' or open the 'Directory' menu item and select 'Groups'. Follow the instructions. You can only add existing Workspace users to the group.

@Blindspots Thank you. I'll have a look at those resources.
